# Fetch Data According To Specific Entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, magicalrecord

I am using magical record to fetch data from core data, using the code:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (!_fetchedResultsController ) {
        _fetchedResultsController = [TagItem MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:nil withPredicate:nil  sortedBy:@"name" ascending:YES delegate:self];
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

The problem is, it is populating a table view controller that is pushed to by another table view controller, so basically a user selects an option which takes the person to a list of data, but the data within the option is specific to that option. So what I want to do is fetch only the data that is assigned to that option, rather than simply displaying all the data available. My method above only allows me to obtain all the data, rather than selecting specific data according to the option. The data within the option is given the objectId of the option itself as an entity and thus provides a relationship between the two.

So my question is, how do I go about fetching data according to a specific entity, using magical record?

UPDATE

I have tried setting the predicate to a specific value just to test if it works, thinking it would work the same as just working with core data alone, but I just get an error.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (!_fetchedResultsController ) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = test"];
        _fetchedResultsController = [TagItem MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:nil withPredicate:predicate  sortedBy:@"name" ascending:YES delegate:self];
    }



return _fetchedResultsController;
```

}

The error is as below, even though I know for certain there is a data item with the name test stored, nonetheless it doesn't seem to work.

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to generate SQL for predicate (name == test) (problem on RHS)'

Comment: The quoting in your test predicate is wrong: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = 'test'"]` or better: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", @"test"]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what the `withPredicate` parameter is for:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = ... // predicate that filters the items to display
_fetchedResultsController = [TagItem MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:nil withPredicate:predicate ...];
```

For example, if *TagItem* has a to-one relationship `person` to *Person*, then

```
Person *person = ...; // person selected in the first view controller
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"person = %@", person];
_fetchedResultsController = [TagItem MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:nil withPredicate:predicate ...];
```

would fetch all items related to that person.

Comment: So there's my daft realisation, you cannot simply enter the name of the entity into the predicate. Thanks a lot it's working if I do it that way! :D

Comment: @AlexSaidani: You can (with the right quoting), see my comment to your question.

Comment: It is unrelated to the above question but which will be faster :- 

Executing predicate where person={person object}

or person.field={some value} ?

My personal thinking is that the second option will be faster since Core Data only needs to compare one field whereas for the first code, it will be comparing all the properties. However, I am not sure

Comment: @Max: "person={person object}" does not compare all properties. The related object is stored as one column (like a "foreign key") in the SQLite table, and I assume that this will be faster than "person.field={some value}" which requires string comparisons. You can add "-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1" to the launch arguments, then you will see all executed SQLite statements with timing information.

Comment: @Martin R:- Thank you. I compared both the approaches. The person.field approach produced a join with my other table on its indexed field. And the "person == " approach did not generated any join... the field approach took 0.0201 sec while the second approach took 0.0278 sec. Although there was no data in the person table ( :) ). But, atleast I now know the difference between both approaches